# How to add spacings within one line?

Tags: spacing, line

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{114514}

\usepackage[fontset=none]{ctex}
\setCJKmainfont{Adobe Song Std}[BoldFont=Noto Sans CJK SC Medium]

\begin{document}
哼哼哼啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊$\dfrac{1}{2}$啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊
\end{document}
```

for example, I want to add spacings upward and below the 1/2, but \baselinestretch is of no use, what should I do?

[image]

Comment: Try `\usepackage[linespread=1.5]{ctex}` or larger value.

Comment: Thanks! `\linespread{1.5}` is OK, but [here](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/138408387) says that `\linespread` should be equal to `\renewcommand\baselinestretch`. I want to know what is their difference

Comment: Your `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{}` command need put after the command `\usepackage{ctex}` , otherwise, it will be overwritten by package `ctex`

Comment: They are doing the same thing basically.

Comment: `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{114514}` means that lines should be over one hundred thousand times further apart than normal. You presumably don't want that?

Comment: I tried 1.25 1.5 2 and even 114514 but the spacings upward and below the 1/2 does not change even a pixel.

Comment: @1900011604 Did you see the my comment yesterday, You need put the command after `\usepackage{ctex}`

Comment: thanks @Tom, it works too.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set a higher value to `\lineskiplimit` (standard is 0pt) and to `\lineskip` (standard is 1pt).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
%\renewcommand\baselinestretch{114514}

\usepackage[fontset=none]{ctex}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSong}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\lineskip}{4pt}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{6pt}

哼哼哼啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊
啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊
啊啊啊$\dfrac{1}{2}$啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊
啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to increase the interline space between *all* lines, increase the `\baselinestretch` (standard for `ctex` is 1.3).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\usepackage[fontset=none]{ctex}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSong}

\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

哼哼哼啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊
啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊
啊啊啊$\dfrac{1}{2}$啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊
啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊啊

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`\usepackage[linespread=1.5]{ctex}` or `\linespread{1.5}` or using `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}`

all these commands should write after loading ctex